# Controller/actuator to perform database actions by URL, loop never-ending

Tags: php, arrays, url, content-management-system, infinite-loop

I'm writing a simple AJAX/jquery CMS for a website i'm building. To simplify everything, I want to simply make requests to URLs to perform actions (much like what Magento has - but I have my reasons not to use Magento/other existing options)

The problem is that the while loop doesn't end (and at the time of writing the PHP docs are timing out where I am so I can't access them).

```
<?php
$query = explode('/',parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
$qs = array();
foreach ($query as $key=>$value) $qs[$key] = urldecode(htmlspecialchars($value));

# /action/{$class-name}/{$action}/{$field1}/{$param1}/{$field2}/{$param2}/.../{$fieldN}/{$paramN}
# e.g.
# /action/QuickOverview/get/internal_name/value
# /action/QuickOverview/update/internal_name/value1/title/value2/

$params = array();
array_shift($qs);
switch ($val = array_shift($qs)) {
    case "action":
        $className = array_shift($qs);
        $action = array_shift($qs);
        $field = true;
        while ($val=array_shift($qs)!==false) {
            if ($field) $params[-1] = $val;
            else $params[$params[-1]] = $val;
            $field = !$field;
        }
        unset($params[-1]);
        break;
    default:
        var_dump("Unknown value: ".$val);
        break;
}

var_dump($params);
?>
```

The page times out (probably looping forever), how can I end this while loop correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` is an assignment operator and shouldn't be used for a condition check, this case in the `while` loop.

Try:

```
switch ($val = array_shift($qs)) {
case "action":
    $className = array_shift($qs);
    $action = array_shift($qs);
    $field = true;
    while ($val == array_shift($qs)) {
        if ($field) $params[-1] = $val;
        else $params[$params[-1]] = $val;
        $field = !$field;
    }
    unset($params[-1]);
    break;
default:
    var_dump("Unknown value: ".$val);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Actually I was assigning the result of array_shift to $val at the same time. While my net was down, I found that `$val = array_shift($qs)` did the trick (i.e. without the `!==false`). Thanks though. P.S. FYI php is evaluating `while($val)` not `while($val == array_shift($qs))`

Comment: I have to correct myself, this didn't work when the param was '0' (that variable was left out). So the correct solution was this: `while(!is_null($val=array_shift($qs)))`.